# Extract word between two words

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I receive text data in a field in Snowflake in the following format :

Phone number 99999999999 was flagged by: XXXXXXXXX

Phone number 99999999999 was unflagged by: XXXXXXXXX

i.e. the word between 'was' and 'by' can be either flagged or unflagged.

How do I extract the word between 'was' and 'by'

Comment: `/was (.*) by/gm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake regular expression functions do not support lookarounds. If you want to use a lookahead or lookbehind, you'd need to use a JavaScript UDF. To use Snowflake SQL, you can do this (for any word between two other words):

```
set str = 'Phone number 99999999999 was flagged by: XXXXXXXXX';
select split(regexp_substr($str, 'was (.*) by'), ' ')[1]::string;
```

The expression will also grab the start and end words, so this splits the result by space into an array and uses only the second (zero based) word.

+1 to tybocopperkettle for this part:

> Or if you simply need to match "flagged" or "unflagged", you can do:

`(un)?flagged`

In Snowflake SQL, that would be like this:

```
select regexp_substr($str, '(un)?flagged');
```

Comment: Thank you Greg. Both your suggestions worked

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly want to match the content between the words "was" and "by", you can do:

```js
var str1 = "Phone number 99999999999 was flagged by: XXXXXXXXX";
var str2 = "Phone number 99999999999 was unflagged by: XXXXXXXXX";
var regex = /(?<=\Wwas\s).+(?=\sby\W)/;
console.log(str1.match(regex)[0]);
console.log(str2.match(regex)[0]);
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=)` is look-behind which means: only match if preceded by what ever regex is after the `?<=`.
- `\W` matches any character that *isn't* a letter or a number, this is so that "way" can't just be the end of words like "highway", but could have punctuation directly before it.
- `was` matches the literal string "was".
- `\s` is any whitespace character.
- `.+` matches any character (the `.`) 1 or more times (`+`).
- `(?=)` is look-ahead which, as you can imagine, means only match if the regex is *pro*ceeded by the regex after the `?=`.

Or if you simply need to match "flagged" or "unflagged", you can do:

```js
var str1 = "Phone number 99999999999 was flagged by: XXXXXXXXX";
var str2 = "Phone number 99999999999 was unflagged by: XXXXXXXXX";
var regex = /(un)?flagged/;
console.log(str1.match(regex)[0]);
console.log(str2.match(regex)[0]);
```

Explanation:

- `(un)` matches "un" in a character group.
- `?` means match the previous match zero or one times. If we hadn't put "un" in parentheses, it would match a "u" then zero or one n's.
- `flagged` just matches the string "flagged".

Comment: @Cary Swoveland Thank you, I was aware of the 1st issue but though it might be fine in reachbgk's context, but didn't realize the issue with number 3 and 4. I'll edit my answer.